# Print some text depending page number on pdf while generating pdf through xslt and xsl:fo

Tags: java, xml, xslt, xsl-fo

I am using following lib/namespaces to generate pdf out of xml

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" 
    xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
    xmlns:fo="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Format"
    xmlns:fn="http://www.w3.org/2005/xpath-functions"
    xmlns:math="http://exslt.org/math" 
    xmlns:exslt="http://exslt.org/common"
    xmlns:str="http://exslt.org/strings"
    exclude-result-prefixes="exslt math str">
```

my requirement is that i want to print some text fo:block-container text will print on second page.

```
<fo:block-container xsl:use-attribute-sets="section border_red">
    <fo:block xsl:use-attribute-sets="header">Product:</fo:block>                   
        <xsl:for-each select="ROWSET2/ROWSET2_ROW">
            <fo:block xsl:use-attribute-sets="paragraph indented"><xsl:value-of select="PRODUCTNAME"/></fo:block>
        </xsl:for-each>
        <!-- when page not first print something at the end of this block -->               
</fo:block-container>
```

So print inside the block when block overflow to 2ed, 3ed .. page, if block is complete on first page not text printing required.

> Tried "fo:retrieve-table-marker"

:

```
                <fo:table>
                    <fo:table-header>
                        <fo:table-cell>
                            <fo:block xsl:use-attribute-sets="header">Product:
                            </fo:block>
                        </fo:table-cell>
                    </fo:table-header>

                    <fo:table-footer>
                        <fo:table-row>
                            <fo:table-cell>

                                <fo:retrieve-table-marker
                                    retrieve-class-name="test123" retrieve-boundary-within-table="table"
                                    retrieve-position-within-table="last-starting" />

                            </fo:table-cell>
                        </fo:table-row>
                    </fo:table-footer>

                    <fo:table-body>
                        <xsl:for-each select="ROWSET2/ROWSET2_ROW">
                            <xsl:choose>
                                <xsl:when test="position() != last()">
                                    <fo:table-row>
                                        <fo:marker marker-class-name="test123">To be continued...
                                        </fo:marker>
                                        <fo:table-cell>
                                            <fo:block xsl:use-attribute-sets="paragraph indented">
                                                <xsl:value-of select="PRODUCTNAME" />
                                            </fo:block>
                                        </fo:table-cell>
                                    </fo:table-row>
                                </xsl:when>
                                <xsl:otherwise>
                                    <fo:table-row>
                                        <fo:marker marker-class-name="test123"></fo:marker>
                                        <fo:table-cell>
                                            <fo:block xsl:use-attribute-sets="paragraph indented">
                                                <xsl:value-of select="PRODUCTNAME" />
                                                last
                                            </fo:block>
                                        </fo:table-cell>
                                    </fo:table-row>
                                </xsl:otherwise>
                            </xsl:choose>
                        </xsl:for-each>
                    </fo:table-body>
                </fo:table>
```

Answer (score 2):

If your requirement is outputting special text at the end of page when fo:block-container breaks into multiple pages, there are no such function in XSL 1.1 and extensions from XSL-FO processor vendors (as far as I know).

However if you use fo:table, fo:table-footer, fo:retrieve-table-marker and fo:marker with table outer rule and entry with no rule per one row, it is possible to output special text when the table breaks into multiple pages.

[[XSL 1.1] 6.7.7 fo:table-footer](https://www.w3.org/TR/xsl11/#fo_table-footer)

[[XSL 1.1] 6.13.7 fo:retrieve-table-marker](https://www.w3.org/TR/xsl11/#fo_retrieve-table-marker)="

[[XSL 1.1] 6.13.5 fo:marker](https://www.w3.org/TR/xsl11/#fo_marker)

See example snapshot from following blog post (Japanese):

[テーブルのタイトルに"(Continued)"と出す． (3)](https://blogs.yahoo.co.jp/tnakita/14956757.html)

[image: Frist Page]

[image: Second Page]

[image: Last Page]

In this example, "Continues to next page" is defined in fo:marker in fo:table-cell and displayed in fo:table-footer by fo:retrieve-table-marker.

The sample data:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<ROOT>
    <ROWSET2>
        <ROWSET2_ROW><PRODUCTNAME>Product1</PRODUCTNAME></ROWSET2_ROW>
        <ROWSET2_ROW><PRODUCTNAME>Product2</PRODUCTNAME></ROWSET2_ROW>
        ...
        <ROWSET2_ROW><PRODUCTNAME>Product24</PRODUCTNAME></ROWSET2_ROW>
        <ROWSET2_ROW><PRODUCTNAME>Product25</PRODUCTNAME></ROWSET2_ROW>
    </ROWSET2>
</ROOT>
```

The sample code:

```
<xsl:template match="ROOT">
    <fo:table width="100%">
        <fo:table-header>
            <fo:table-cell>
                <fo:block xsl:use-attribute-sets="header">Product:
                </fo:block>
            </fo:table-cell>
        </fo:table-header>
        <fo:table-footer>
            <fo:table-row>
                <fo:table-cell>
                    <fo:retrieve-table-marker
                        retrieve-class-name="test123"/>
                </fo:table-cell>
            </fo:table-row>
        </fo:table-footer>
        <fo:table-body>
            <xsl:for-each select="ROWSET2/ROWSET2_ROW">
                <fo:table-row>
                    <fo:table-cell>
                        <fo:block xsl:use-attribute-sets="paragraph indented">
                            <xsl:choose>
                                <xsl:when test="position() = 1">
                                    <fo:marker marker-class-name="test123">
                                        <fo:block xsl:use-attribute-sets="indented" color="teal">To be continued...</fo:block>
                                    </fo:marker>
                                </xsl:when>
                                <xsl:when test="position() = last()">
                                    <fo:marker marker-class-name="test123"/>
                                </xsl:when>
                            </xsl:choose>
                            <xsl:value-of select="PRODUCTNAME" />
                            <xsl:if test="position()=last()">
                                <fo:inline> Last</fo:inline>
                            </xsl:if>
                        </fo:block>
                    </fo:table-cell>
                </fo:table-row>
            </xsl:for-each>
        </fo:table-body>
    </fo:table>
</xsl:template>
```

The sample result:

[image: The sample PDF]

Comment: @p27 I added the example.

Comment: thanks for your reply. I have tried your code as well its not working for me. I have also tried with different version of  apache fop, apache fop version 1.0 footing is not printing but pdf is generated file, with apache fop 2.3 i got java null pointer Exception at some point of stylesheet and pdf is not generated, please let me know which version of apache fop you are using and version of xsl.

Comment: Unfortunately I use AHFormatter rather than FOP. Also [Apache™ FOP Compliance Page](https://xmlgraphics.apache.org/fop/compliance.html) indicates that fo:retrieve-table-marker is still "partial conformance" level. It may better to report difficulity to Apache™ FOP Users Mailing List.

Answer (score 0):

Found solution:
following code is working with apache fop2.3

when I used `<fo:inline>` inside of `<fo:marker>` then its working.

```
    <fo:table width="100%" xsl:use-attribute-sets="section border_red">
            <fo:table-header>
                <fo:table-cell>
                    <fo:block xsl:use-attribute-sets="header">Product:
                    </fo:block>
                </fo:table-cell>
            </fo:table-header>
            <fo:table-footer>
                <fo:table-row>
                    <fo:table-cell>
                        <fo:block text-align="end">
                        <fo:retrieve-table-marker
                            retrieve-class-name="test123"
                            retrieve-boundary-within-table="table"
                            retrieve-position-within-table="last-ending"
                            />
                        </fo:block>
                    </fo:table-cell>
                </fo:table-row>
            </fo:table-footer>
            <fo:table-body>
                <xsl:for-each select="ROWSET2/ROWSET2_ROW">
                    <fo:table-row>
                        <fo:table-cell>
                            <fo:block xsl:use-attribute-sets="paragraph indented">
                                <xsl:choose>
                                    <xsl:when test="position() = 1">
                                        <fo:marker marker-class-name="test123">                                        
                                            <fo:inline>To be continued...</fo:inline>
                                        </fo:marker>
                                    </xsl:when>
                                    <xsl:when test="position() = last()">
                                        <fo:marker marker-class-name="test123"/>
                                    </xsl:when>
                                </xsl:choose>
                                <xsl:value-of select="PRODUCTNAME" />
                                <xsl:if test="position()=last()">
                                    <fo:inline>Last..</fo:inline>
                                </xsl:if>
                            </fo:block>
                        </fo:table-cell>
                    </fo:table-row>
                </xsl:for-each>
            </fo:table-body>
        </fo:table>
```

Comment: Glad to see your success!